# How to add and update map entry using Java Streams API

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-stream

I just begin to learn Streams, and I have a task to count and sort all words in some array of String. I have already parsed my input to words, but I don't know how to add and update entry using the stream.

There is my parsing stream:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = lines.stream().flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+")));
        String[] parsed =  stringStream.toArray(String[]::new);
```

I have done this task without streams just like this:

```
Map<String,WordStatistics> wordToFrequencyMap = new HashMap<>();
for (String line: lines) {
    line=line.toLowerCase();
    String[] mas =  line.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
    for (String word:mas) {
        if(word.length()>3) {
            if (!wordToFrequencyMap.containsKey(word)) {
                wordToFrequencyMap.put(word, new WordStatistics(word, 1));
            } else {
                WordStatistics tmp = wordToFrequencyMap.get(word);
                tmp.setFreq(tmp.getFreq() + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WordStatistics class:

```
public class WordStatistics implements Comparable<WordStatistics>{
    private String word;
    private int freq;

    public WordStatistics(String word, int freq) {
        this.word = word;
        this.freq = freq;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public int getFreq() {
        return freq;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void setFreq(int freq) {
        this.freq = freq;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(WordStatistics o) {
        if(this.freq > o.freq)
            return 1;
        if(this.freq == o.freq)
        {
            return -this.word.compareTo(o.word);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the benefit of this `WordStatistics` class? A `Map<String,Integer>` or `Map<String,Long>` does already describe word frequencies sufficiently.

Comment: @Holger I also need to sort my entries by its frequencies and then in alphabetical order if needed (if the words have the same frequency), and because of it I decided to store frequency and word together. I have this comparing in the `compareTo` method.

Comment: You can not sort a `Map`, so your sorting operation would have to store the data into a new collection anyway and that again doesn’t require this class, e.g. `lines.stream() .flatMap(Pattern.compile ( "[^a-zA-Z]+")::splitAsStream) .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) .entrySet().stream() .sorted(Map.Entry.<String,Long>comparingByValue().reversed().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())) .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);` Not implementing a custom `compareTo` method prevents you from making mistakes like using minus (minus can overflow) to reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is collecting [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) with a merge function:

```
Map<String, WordStatistics> wordToFrequencyMap = lines.stream()
        .map(s -> s.split("[^a-zA-Z]+"))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w, w -> new WordStatistics(w, 1), (ws1, ws2) -> {
            ws1.setFreq(ws1.getFreq() + ws2.getFreq());
            return ws1;
        }));
```

To break down the `toMap()` arguments:

- `w -> w` just means use the stream element as the map key.
- The next argument produces a value for the key, which is initially a new instance of `WordStatistics` with a frequency of `1`.
- Finally, we tell the collector how to merge values together when they belong to the same key. In our case, we sum the frequencies into one of the values (`ws1`) and return that as the merge result.

Comment: Thank you, it does work pretty nice! There's one thing I can't figure out, can you clarify how this code is working, especially that part with the lambdas?

`.collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w, w -> new WordStatistics(w, 1), (ws1, ws2) -> {ws1.setFreq(ws1.getFreq() + ws2.getFreq());`

Comment: @Wtht.Nws Added some explanation. See the linked Javadoc for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This should do pretty much the same you are doing in your loop right now.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]+");
lines.stream().flatMap(pattern::splitAsStream).filter(s -> s.length() > 3).forEach(s -> {
    WordStatistics tmp = wordToFrequencyMap.get(s);
    if (tmp == null) {
        wordToFrequencyMap.put(s, new WordStatistics(word, 1));
    } else {
        tmp.setFreq(tmp.getFreq() + 1);
    }
});
```